# Property of a quasi-uniform triangulation

Tags: finite-element-method, triangulation

I have some type of proof for the inverse inequality:
$|\nabla v |_{H^1} \le C |v|_{H^1}$

This proof uses the following property for quasi-uniform triangulations:
$ \frac{\int_{{K}^\wedge}{|\nabla v^\wedge |}^2}{\int_{K^\wedge}|{v}^\wedge |^2} \le C$

the wedge refers to the reference triangle. So $K^\wedge$ is the reference triangle and $v^\wedge$ is the test function on the reference triangle. I'm not sure what type of semi-norm it is, but I assume it's either $L^2$ or $H^1$.

I do not understand why this property is true. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please explain the notation

Comment: I have tried clarifying the notations more...

Comment: Inverse inequalities are usually shown for the grid functions. Can you specify what do you mean by a test function? If it’s a polynomial, the estimate is easy. If you mean $H^1$, think of a series of bounded but highly oscillating functions, they will fail the estimate you want. Sorry if I have misunderstood your intentions.